# Why java thread has the same thread name?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm learning java concurrency. There is a strange question of my code. My code simply implement a producer and a consumer. When I setting a different thread name in the loop, but the log always print some same thread name. What's the reason about it?

```
package org.example.ch5._1_1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class WaitAndNotify {

    private final Object lock = new Object();

    private final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    private final Random random = new Random();

    public void producer() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (list.size() == 10) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            list.add(random.nextInt(100));
            if (list.size() == 10) {
                log.info("thread-{},{}", Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                        Arrays.toString(list.toArray(new Integer[0])));
            }
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void consumer() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (list.size() < 10) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            list.clear();
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    static class MyProducer implements Runnable {

        private final WaitAndNotify waitAndNotify;

        public MyProducer(WaitAndNotify waitAndNotify) {
            this.waitAndNotify = waitAndNotify;
        }

        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 10;
            while (i > 0) {
                waitAndNotify.producer();
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    static class MyConsumer implements Runnable {

        private final WaitAndNotify waitAndNotify;

        public MyConsumer(WaitAndNotify waitAndNotify) {
            this.waitAndNotify = waitAndNotify;
        }

        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                waitAndNotify.consumer();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WaitAndNotify waitAndNotify = new WaitAndNotify();
        Runnable runnable = new MyProducer(waitAndNotify);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Thread producer = new Thread(runnable, "producer-" + i);
            producer.start();
        }
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new MyConsumer(waitAndNotify), "consumer");
        consumer.start();
    }
}
```

Here is my log. producer-17 appears 3 times and producer-11 appears 3 times. There is no producer-2 or producer-5 in the log. What's wrong in my code?

```
2022-03-21 17:32:42,014 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-0] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-0,[49, 96, 0, 43, 23, 6, 79, 44, 28, 21]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,019 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-17] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-17,[92, 56, 9, 43, 77, 24, 53, 74, 44, 85]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,019 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-1] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-1,[86, 11, 10, 58, 5, 86, 3, 68, 73, 24]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,020 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-17] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-17,[10, 9, 97, 41, 81, 35, 84, 0, 86, 12]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,020 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-3] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-3,[13, 90, 30, 45, 1, 8, 43, 68, 49, 26]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,020 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-17] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-17,[81, 19, 34, 58, 89, 66, 74, 76, 20, 5]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,021 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-4] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-4,[48, 60, 0, 36, 97, 9, 42, 44, 67, 81]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,021 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-16] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-16,[77, 38, 17, 63, 71, 7, 80, 64, 61, 19]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,021 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-6] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-6,[47, 56, 50, 7, 89, 45, 32, 91, 97, 66]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,022 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-16] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-16,[27, 96, 24, 85, 3, 28, 23, 21, 93, 72]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,022 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-7] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-7,[4, 95, 19, 95, 42, 9, 49, 5, 54, 8]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,022 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-13] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-13,[43, 81, 97, 19, 40, 65, 48, 32, 61, 77]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,023 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-14] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-14,[67, 81, 84, 11, 73, 71, 65, 26, 78, 45]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,023 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-12] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-12,[54, 48, 67, 88, 0, 78, 99, 12, 49, 84]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,023 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-7] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-7,[58, 66, 53, 39, 14, 64, 2, 57, 27, 91]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,023 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-11] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-11,[91, 79, 70, 36, 34, 28, 63, 67, 17, 77]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,024 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-10] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-10,[2, 76, 42, 92, 91, 87, 64, 20, 25, 3]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,024 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-9] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-9,[46, 57, 98, 0, 28, 68, 63, 71, 97, 54]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,024 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-11] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-11,[26, 66, 10, 77, 69, 41, 77, 80, 21, 55]
2022-03-21 17:32:42,024 INFO  [learning-concurrency][producer-11] org.example.ch5._1_1.WaitAndNotify producer(33): thread-producer-11,[94, 97, 84, 87, 85, 53, 77, 88, 79, 84]
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not the point. I want the log print different thread name.

Comment: It does. It prints several different producer threads' names. If you're expecting a certain sequence or amount, then you have the wrong expectations.

Comment: Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: I don't understand why producer-2 is missing?

Comment: This is the project name. The thread name is behind it.

Comment: @Kayaman he's not expecting a sequence. It's a basic for loop that launches and names threads so he is not expecting any duplicates in naming nor any missing producers like producer-2.

Comment: A producer thread only logs something if it was the thread that added the 10th item to the list. There is no guarantee that every thread will have the chance to add the 10th item into the list - maybe everytime `producer-2` runs it will add the first item to an empty list.

Comment: But the total thread is always 20. Why some thread execute more than one time?

Comment: You seem to assume that scheduling is always perfectly fair and without variance. That's not the case. Some of your threads could just happen to be scheduled for more activity than others, for reasons that are various and at your point in learning should probably just be summarized as "OS and CPU magic". By executing stuff in multiple threads you give up the total control over who does what exactly when. If you need that, then write single-threaded code (or learn **a lot more** about multithreading).

Comment: documentation of `notifyAll()`: *"Wakes up all threads that are waiting ... The awakened threads will compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might be actively competing to synchronize on this object; for example, the awakened threads enjoy no reliable privilege or disadvantage in being the next thread to lock this object."*

Comment: It would be perfectly valid to schedule those threads in round-robin fashion: `producer-0` adds the first element, `producer-1` adds the second element, ... `producer-9` adds the 10th element and logs the values, followed by the consumer consuming everything. Then repeat this sequence 9 times, followed by a similar sequence with `producer-10` to `producer-19`. In such a case you would only see `producer-9` and `producer-19` in the log.

Comment: But you still not explain my question yet...

Comment: They did explain. Now it’s your turn to read and understand. Besides that, there’s no sense in an expression like `Arrays.toString(list.toArray(new Integer[0]))`. It produces exactly the same output as a straight-forward `list.toString()`.

Comment: _What's wrong in my code?_ From the log you cannot conclude whether a specific thread did run or not because you only log the thread name when the list reaches 10 elements and there is no guarantee that all threads will reach that mark (a thread could always be scheduled when the list is empty so that every time that thread executes `producer()` the size of the list is 1 when `list.size() == 10` is tested)